# Node.JS: Sequelize association set fails to restore record on paranoid

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 models `users` and `tags`, both are associated through another model called `usersTags` and all 3 models have paranoid set with custom timestamps. I understand that associating models will add additional methods to work on the associations to all associated models, so i am wanting to making a simple `setTags` call for users, the docs shows that if in the array in the method does not contain the element that is stored in the database it should be removed, otherwise it should be created/restored.

So i try to restore a previously removed `tag` but for some reason it fails. The models are defined as following:

**Users**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const Users = sequelize.define("users", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        username: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false,
            validate: {
                len: {
                    args: [3, 100],
                    msg: "String length is not in this range"
                }
            }
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
            allowNull: false,
            field: "password_hash"
        }
    }, {
        tableName: "users",
        createdAt: "create_time",
        updatedAt: "update_time",
        deletedAt: "delete_time",
        paranoid: true
    });

    Users.associate = function(models) {
        // Add this association to include tag records
        this.belongsToMany(models.tags, {
            through: {
                model: models.usersTags,
                unique: true
            },
            foreignKey: "users_id",
            constraints: false
        });
    };

    return Users;
};
```

**Tags**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const Tags = sequelize.define("tags", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        tableName: "tags",
        createdAt: "create_time",
        updatedAt: "update_time",
        deletedAt: "delete_time",
        paranoid: true
    });

    Tags.associate = function(models) {
        this.belongsToMany(models.users, {
            through: {
                model: models.usersTags,
                unique: true
            },
            foreignKey: "tags_id",
            constraints: false
        });
    };

    return Tags;
};
```

**usersTags**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const UsersTags = sequelize.define("usersTags", {
        users_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            references: {
                model: "users",
                key: "id"
            }
        },
        tags_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            references: {
                model: "tags",
                key: "id"
            }
        }
    }, {
        tableName: "users_tags",
        createdAt: "create_time",
        updatedAt: "update_time",
        deletedAt: "delete_time",
        paranoid: true,
        indexes: [
            {
                unique: true,
                fields: ["users_id", "tags_id"]
            }
        ]
    });

    return UsersTags;
};
```

**Test**

```
let _user;

models.users.findOne({where: {id: 100}})
    .then(user => {
        _user = user;

        return _user.setTags([1]);          // Successfully create association tag with id 1
    })
    .then(() => _user.setTags([]))   // Successfully remove all associated tags
    .then(() => _user.setTags([1])); // Should restore association tag with id 1 but fails
```

**Executed query**

```
app:database Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `birthday`, `description`, `location`, `email`, `type`, `image_path` FROM `users` AS `users` WHERE ((`users`.`delete_time` > '2018-08-28 19:40:15' OR `users`.`delete_time` IS NULL) AND `users`.`id` = 100); +0ms
app:database Executing (default): SELECT `users_id`, `tags_id`, `create_time`, `update_time`, `delete_time` FROM `users_tags` AS `usersTags` WHERE ((`usersTags`.`delete_time` > '2018-08-28 19:40:15' OR `usersTags`.`delete_time` IS NULL) AND `usersTags`.`users_id` = 100); +6ms
app:database Executing (default): INSERT INTO `users_tags` (`users_id`,`tags_id`,`create_time`,`update_time`) VALUES (100,1,'2018-08-28 19:40:15','2018-08-28 19:40:15'); +7ms
```

For some reason the tag search query is failing to retrieve the tag that contains the delete_time set and therefore the last query is `insert` instead of `update`, i know the workaround would be to set `paranoid` to false but i have to keep track of all activities, i know another workaround would be to create a custom model method to handle this but i still want to know if there is a way to achieve this without having to create an additional custom method

Answer (score 0):

your code in not in a correct async order so your `_user` global variable is not initiated,I think this is the correct order :

```
let _user;

models.users.findOne({where: {id: 100}})
.then(user => {
    _user = user;
    _user.setTags([]).then(()=>{
        _user.setTags([1])
    })
})
```

Comment: I forgot to add a return, the orignal code does have a return.. i edited my question for this fix